# HIVE on MR3: ERROR [main] client.ClientLocalResourceUtils$: Invalid URI ${liburis} in getUriFileStatuses()

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm trying to setup Hive on Mr3 on Hadoop, when running the hiveserver2, it faild because the MR3 client can't be created.

I got the following error:

```
2020-06-18T14:28:29,778 ERROR [main] client.ClientLocalResourceUtils$: Invalid URI ${liburis} in getUriFileStatuses()
2020-06-18T14:28:29,778 ERROR [main] session.MR3Session: Failed to start MR3 Session com.datamonad.mr3.api.common.MR3Exception: MR3SessionClient.startApplication()
Caused by: com.datamonad.mr3.api.common.MR3UncheckedException: Invalid URI ${liburis} in getUriFileStatuses()
```

Answer (score 0):

I sloved the problem by pointing the jar files in the hdfs appropriate folder.